# VPN to Internal Network - How to access IIS sites

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, windows-server-2012, iis

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to configure this.

I am using a VPN connection to connect to our Softlayer servers private network.

Ideally what i'd like to do is have access to our websites that are locked down and shouldn't be available publicly - however the issue is that their DNS is external (through godaddy).

Here is what i'm considering doing -but i'm not sure if there is a better way to set this up.

1. setup windows DNS on webserver
2. limit windows DNS to the private network interface only
3. setup entries in windows DNS for private websites
4. setup vpn to use/assign this dns server IP

   `a. how can i set it up so that if my DNS doesn't resolve an address it will fallback to an external DNS server? not sure if this is automatic?`
5. setup IIS host header entries for new internal website names (mysite.internal) - etc etc
   `a. how can i install SSL on these sites, i do have SSL but its tied to these sites external domain names?`

Hopefully i provided enough information - i'm really new to all this and i'm not certain the best way to configure this or proceed.

Comment: the quick and dirty way would be to edit the `hosts` files on the client machines. Nothing else needed.

Comment: Another quick way is to just create an A record on your internal DNS server that points to the internal IP address of the NIC that hosts the site.... I'm not sure if your VPN connected machines are on a different subnet, but if you can route to it from the subnet and per the VPN configuration, then your internal DNS server should have no problem setting up an internal DNS record to point to its internal IP address per the VPN configuration and however it routes to that macine/subnet to allow access.

Answer (score 0):

4. On the DNS Server; you have option to specify forwarders. Any domain that is not setup on the DNS will be resolved using the DNS servers specified as Forwarders. On windows machine, it is automatic, since it has Root Hints.
5. There is no work around. You cannot use SSL for a domain that it is not issued for. You can however use the same Domain name internally, if there is no need to resolve it externanally. For example. www.yourdomain.com can resolve to 123.45.67.89 externally, and 10.1.1.1 internally (on your DNS server).